# Difference in output between While and For loop JavaScript - Newbee

Tags: javascript, for-loop, while-loop

It's a basic question;
I can't seem to understand why in the code below
the ***while loop*** output begins with 2 "#" and the ***for loop*** start with 1

[image: Console Log Screenshot]

```
let brick = "#";
while (brick.length < 8){

 brick += "#";
  console.log(brick);
}
console.log("For Loop");
for (let i = "#"; i.length <8; i+="#"){
 console.log(i) 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because in the `while` loop, you are incrementing ***before*** and in the `for` loop ***after*** writing to the console.

Move your `brick += "#";` to the end of the `while` loop and they will behave both the same way:

```js
let brick = "#";

while (brick.length < 8) {
    console.log(brick);
    brick += "#";
}
```

For-Loop:

```js
for (let i = "#"; i.length < 8; i += "#")
                                  ^ happens AFTER each iteration
```

Answer (score 0):

You have already instatiated the brick at the start. But, when you are looping in the `for` loop the length is increased after the loop is finished. And the opposite is happening in the `while` loop.